# Error happened to appened javascript html code to blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Error

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: D:\Codes\Php\Laravel\appoint_now-master1\resources\views\staff\schedule\edit.blade.php)
```

blade code

```
<form action="{{route('staff.schedule.AddHour',$day->id)}}" method="post"  id="formHours-{{ $day->id }}"  >
 @csrf
@method('put')
<input type="hidden"  value="{{$day->id}}" name="staff_schedule_day_id" required>
</form>
```

controller code

```
public function addHour(Request $request,$staffSchedule)
    {
        $user = auth()->guard(GuardType::STAFF)->user();

        $request->validate([
            'staff_schedule_day_id' => 'required',
            'start_time' => 'required',
            'end_time' => 'required',
        ]);

        $staffSchedulesDaysHours=new StaffScheduleDayHour();
        $staffSchedulesDaysHours->staff_schedule_day_id = $request->staff_schedule_day_id;
        $staffSchedulesDaysHours->start_time = $request->start_time;
        $staffSchedulesDaysHours->end_time = $request->end_time;
        $staffSchedulesDaysHours->save();


       

return view('staff.schedule.edit')->with('success', trans('messages.itemUpdated'));
    }
```

javascript

```
 function addHour(day_id)
                {
                    const id = `hour-${makeId(5)}`;
                    let html = "";
                    html += `<div class="input-group" id="${id}">`;
                    html += `<input type="time" class="form-control " value="" name="start_time[]"  required>`;
                    html += `<input type="time" class="form-control " value="" name="end_time[]"  required>`;
                    html += `<div class="input-group-append">`;
                    html += `<button class="btn btn-danger"  type="submit">`;
                    html += `Submit`;
                    html += `</button>`;
                    html += `<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="removeHour('${id}')">`;
                    html += `<i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i>`;
                    html += `</button>`;
                    html += `</div>`;
                    html += `</div>`;

                    $(`#formHours-${day_id}`).append(html);
                }
```

I am try to add start_time and end_time as array to my database table schedule_hours as json objects table columes  are set as jason object for both  start_time and end_time. when i press submit button it display the error.
I forgot to say that hour model is also  protect cast as array variable of start_time and end_time. i don't  know where the error is come from. please help me

Comment: `$day->id` is an string or array?

Comment: $day->id is from table schedule_day and its used to foreach as $day. and you asking id is string

Comment: The error is happened when I put start_time[],end_time[]. With out [ ] is ok to work.

Comment: What's is the output of `dd($request->start_time);`?

Comment: array:2 [▼
  0 => "10:30"
  1 => "16:00"
]

Comment: Its an array, you can access by `$request->start_time[0];` and `$request->start_time[1];`

Answer (score 0):

Try converting `$request->start_time` to json before storing it into database.
Use

```
$staffSchedulesDaysHours->start_time = json_encode($request->start_time);
$staffSchedulesDaysHours->end_time = json_encode($request->end_time);
```

Comment: how to decode and display json array to blade?

Comment: Error happened. i do what you say. but i cant display thats values to the blade.

Comment: you can decode the json using json_decode(). But you cannot print the decoded value directly on blade as it is an array and you cannot print an array.